detect device type (mobile phone- pc- access point) from its IP address
I'm developing an android application with kotlin which displays all devices connected to my wifi.
I did this successfully but now I want to display icon with ip address (phone icon- pc- access point- etc...)
like this:

how can I do this ?

You can't.  Not without some additional information from some source.  TCP/IP is device agnostic, there's nothing in the data that tells you what the device is.

what about if I got mac address too ?
is there any way to get device type with mac address ?

No.  That also tells nothing about the device.  It might tell you the manufacturer of the wifi chip (number ranges used to be assigned to different OEMs), but even then it could be straight up lying (many devices allow you to set the mac address these days).  Android even randomly assigns it by default, and will randomly generate new ones.
